# How to get actual index after JPA save and DB triggers executed

Tags: java, oracle, spring-data-jpa

I have `MyEntity` class with `MyDBSequence` for id generation.
I save my MyEntity with MyJpaRepo:

```
Long id = MyJpaRepo.save(new MyEntity());
```

Id was generated based on `MyDBSequence`.For example id has value = `100`.

But after `MyJpaRepo` saved `MyEntity`, database executed trigger on table with `MyEntity`. This trigger increase id (Don't ask why. This is legacy code). Now in base its valu is `101`. But i have value `100` in `id` field.

**Is there any way to get factual id after `MyJpaRepo.save(new MyEntity)`, that was generated after trigger execution?**

I can't edit this trigger now. This is legacy code that need to be support for this moment.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh-java.lang.Object-

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the id is exactly one bigger you could evict the entity from the `EntityManager` and reload it with the id increased by one.